# sql - query between 2 rows

Tags: sql

Have question.  I'm doing a select where I need to grab 2 rows.
I have a value of 13000.00000.  I need to grab both rows 2 and 3 since it
falls between the 10000 (min range) and 15000 (min range)

This statement just pulls in row 2.

```
select *
from TABLE1
where 13000 between TABLE1.MIN_RANGE and TABLE1.MAX_RANGE;
```

TABLE1

```
Row min_range   max_range   return_value
1   0.00000      9999.99900 1.15
2   10000.00000 14999.99900 1.25
3   15000.00000 19999.99900 1.35
4   20000.00000 24999.99900 1.14
```

Comment: 13000 does not fall between the min and max range of row 3, though...

Comment: 13000 is not the range of row 3.

Comment: Actually the min_range for row 3 is 1500, so 1300 is correctly excluded.

Comment: I think the problem is a misunderstanding of how `BETWEEN` works. It operators on values, not on entire rows.

Comment: Is this a challenge? Because I could write a query to do this

Answer (score 3):

You want to get the first row that falls **below** the input and the first row that falls **above** the input, both using `MIN_RANGE` as the descriminator:

```
select top 1 *
from TABLE1
where TABLE1.MIN_RANGE < @input
order by MIN_RANGE desc
UNION
select top 1 *
from TABLE1
where TABLE1.MIN_RANGE >= @input
order by MIN_RANGE;
```

This feels like a solution for a window function, which maybe someone can post.

Comment: more clarification.  Let's say I have a min_range of 13000.  Since it falls between rows 2 and 3 (on the min_range column).  I'd like to pull both those rows.  Thanks again for the help.

Comment: Are you always expecting to have exactly two rows in the result set?

Answer (score 0):

Your output is correct, 13000 does not fall in the range of row 3.

Comment: The OP wants to get two rows (read the question). He wants to use only `MIN_RANGE` as the criteria - not `MAX_RANGE`. So he expects rows 2 and 3 because his input 13000 is *between* 10000 and 15000. He just isn't using `BETWEEN` properly.

Answer (score 0):

The following SQL query should work for you:

```
DECLARE @TestRange NUMERIC(18,0)
SET @TestRange = 13000
SELECT *, (max_range - min_range) 
    FROM TABLE1 
    WHERE ((@TestRange >= min_range AND @TestRange <= max_range) 
       OR ((@TestRange >= min_range -  (max_range - min_range) 
       AND @TestRange <= max_range))) 
    ORDER BY min_range
```

Tested with Microsoft SQL Server. Change the 13000 to whatever value you need to test against, or feel free to hard code the value

Comment: Good answer, but I really don't think he cares about `MAX_RANGE` at all. Take a look at his other question he posted - which is an exact duplicate...

Comment: @Yuck: Yeah I know. The only reason I'm using max_range is because I am always assuming that the NEXT min_range value will always be 0.001 + max_range, which according to his examples, it will be.